# all widgets in my app doesn't showing when I enter the app the seconde time

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-getx

I dont know how exactly describe my problem ,my app works well

it show like this and works fine

[image]

but when I enter to it in the second time it show like this
!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDYnD.jpg)

and it's still working, its just not showing things as it should

[image]

I'm using getx as state management and I'm using it to change theme(dark,light) and the language(english,Arabic)

I dont know even what causes the issue so please help me with any think

I try to change the default language and theme and it's the same issue

> when I face the issue I press the back button to be out of the app and I enter the app again( without removing it from background) it work and everything fine

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible code. Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what code you need I dont know even what cases the problem

Comment: but with chatGPT help it said    "      It's likely that the issue you're experiencing is related to how the app is handling the process being killed by the operating system when it is in the background.

Comment: When the app is running on the Android Studio emulator, it is likely that the emulator is preventing the operating system from killing the app's process, which is why the app behaves as expected. However, when the app is running on a physical device, the operating system may be more aggressive in killing background processes, causing the app's state to be lost.

Comment: One solution to this issue is to use the onWillPop method in your WillPopScope widget to handle the case when the user presses the back button on android devices, this will ensure that you can save your app state before the process is killed by the operating system.

Comment: Another solution is to use the didChangeAppLifecycleState callback in your StatefulWidget to handle any necessary state updates when the app is paused or terminated and save the state in a persistent storage such as shared_preferences or sqflite.

And also check if the lifecycle of your widgets are well handled, for example using the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, this will prevent the widget tree to be recreated when the app is resumed.  "